# How can I turn off A-frame Camera Occlusion Culling?

Tags: aframe

`Occulusion` culling occurs when positioning the `.gltf` model and moving the camera.

I want to control this, but even though the camera's near value is set to the minimum value of 0.001,
the object keeps culling in view. How shall I do it?

**When I'm a little far from the object**
[image: When I'm a little far from the object]

**When I got closer to the object**
[image: When I got closer to the object]

Comment: Could the space defining the size of the model be sufficiently larger than the model itself?

Comment: I think the size of the model was not big enough. This kind of phenomenon was not found in other model files. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: of course! did this effectively solve your issue?

Comment: And I think there are some differences depending on the version.
Objects that disappear from 1.1.0 won't disappear from 0.7.0.

Answer (score 2):

This component should fix the problem. Then add it to your entity.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('no-cull', {
  init() {
    this.el.addEventListener('model-loaded', () => {
      this.el.object3D.traverse(obj => obj.frustumCulled = false)
    })
  },
})
```